# Not able Execute multiple command in remote Machine Using PSEXEC through Perl script

Tags: perl, psexec, siebel

Im trying to connect to remote machine using psexec and and execute multiple commands,

Execution is hanging when im trying to connect to sieb server manager and execute some related command

```
system("cmd /c c:\\PsExec.exe \\\\$host_name  -u  $user_name  -p \ $pwd  cmd /c \" $command1 && srvrmgr/g enterprise server /u username /p password /e siebel /s siebserver /c \"cmd to execute\"\"");
```

i'm running the command through perl script , able to run other commands, only issue is when ,i'm trying to connect to server manager and execute some  related command

Not able to make out what is the issue

Comment: You are using system to call a non perl related exe. print this string to screen, copy and paste it to the command line. This will replicate what the script does and let you check what is wrong. Perhaps one of the variables does not contain what you think it does. See also `perldoc system`

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug the escaping of your command:

```
use 5.012;

my $host_name = 'HOST_NAME';
my $user_name = 'USER_NAME';
my $pwd       = 'PWD';
my $command1  = 'COMMAND1';

my $cmd = "cmd /c c:\\PsExec.exe \\\\$host_name  -u  $user_name  -p \ $pwd  cmd /c \" $command1 && srvrmgr/g enterprise server /u username /p password /e siebel /s siebserver /c \"cmd to execute\"\"";

print $cmd;
```

Outputs:

```
cmd /c c:\PsExec.exe \\HOST_NAME  -u  USER_NAME  -p  PWD  cmd /c " COMMAND1 && srvrmgr/g enterprise server /u username /p password /e siebel /s siebserver /c "cmd to execute""
```

A couple of notes.

1. This backslash `\ $pwd` isn't doing anything
2. These double quotes `"cmd to execute"` probably need to be escaped on the shell level.

Additionally, if you are constructing a command that contains double quotes, it's probably a good idea to use a different delimiter to make your string.

The following is how I would rework your command

```
my $cmd = qq{cmd /c c:\\PsExec.exe \\\\$host_name  -u  $user_name  -p  $pwd  cmd /c " $command1 && srvrmgr/g enterprise server /u username /p password /e siebel /s siebserver /c \\"cmd to execute\\""};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there is space missing between `srvrmgr` command and `/g` parameter